# Scale floating values in selected columns in pandas dataframe to between 0 and 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`;

```
       Name Date        Attr1   Attr2    Attr3 
0      Joe  26-12-2007  53.45  53.4500  52.7200 
1      Joe  27-12-2007  52.38  52.7399  51.0200 
2      Joe  28-12-2007  51.71  51.8500  50.7300
```

I would like to scale the floating values in columns `Attr1`, `Attr2`, `Attr3`
to between 0 and 1. The highest value in a column is scaled to 1. Please note that not all the columns are to be scaled.

I am using Python 3.6.

The following code will scale all the columns but I need to scale selected columns. Another problem is that some columns are in date and string form. The code below will encounter problems converting the values to floating.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(df) 
df.loc[:,:] = scaled_values
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at [sklearn.preprocessing.quantile_transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.quantile_transform.html)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question normalizes all the columns. I need to normalize selected columns.

Comment: Well you hadn't said that at the point I tagged as a duplicate. You've edited it in since.

Comment: And it only normalizes what you choose to pass to the function. Take a subset of the columns and use that. You're not forced to pass the whole df

Comment: @roganjosh, thanks for the hint. I am new to panda. Let me try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is**:

In:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Sara','Martin'],'first':[53.45, 55.51, 51.22],'second':[51.45, 54.51, 57.22],'third':[50.45, 54.51, 58.22]})
data
```

Out:

```
    Name    first   second  third
0   John    53.45   51.45   50.45
1   Sara    55.51   54.51   54.51
2   Martin  51.22   57.22   58.22
```

In:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

sclr = MinMaxScaler()
new_df = sclr.fit_transform(data[['first', 'second', 'third']])
```

Out:

```
array([[ 0.51981352,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.53032929,  0.52252252],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```